# Running IdentityServer4 and API and a Web App from a single 'site'

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

We have a legacy system written in Core MVC 1, using IdentityServer4 for API access and Identity for user management. The site includes a set of API controllers as well, which a mobile application connects to for authentication and data.

We have been having general stability issues, which we have not been able to get to the bottom of. We have decided to upgrade the system to the latest version of MVC Core and in the process IdentityServer4 requires an upgrade.

The problem is that the authentication pipeline has changed dramatically between versions (Core MVC 1 - 2 and Identity 1 - 2) and we are unable to determine a configuration that works.

In short we need:

- Cookie Authentication for web site access
- OAuth 2 password grant flow for app access

However, despite this setup working on the legacy version, it does not seem to want to play ball on the newer setup. It seems we can have one or the other, but not both. There doesn't appear to be any example projects available anywhere that demonstrate such a setup.

I understand this setup is not ideal in that these systems should be split out, and I am going to be making a recommendation as such. I have seen hints of routing api requests through a pipeline setup for Bearer authentication using `MapFrom` but haven't managed to determine a working setup.

UPDATE: Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
        {
            o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

var AuthServerConfig = new IdentityServerConfig(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer"));
            var IdentityCert = AuthServerConfig.GetCerttificate();
            var IdentityConfig = services.AddIdentityServer()
                                         .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(AuthServerConfig.GetIdentityResources())
                                         .AddInMemoryApiResources(AuthServerConfig.GetApiResources())
                                         .AddInMemoryClients(AuthServerConfig.GetClients())
                                         .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

//to secure the API
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
     {
           options.Authority = AuthServerConfig.Settings.RootUrl;
           options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
           options.ApiName = AuthServerConfig.Settings.Scope;
      });
```

And in the Configure Method we have:

```
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

The stage we are at now is that IdentityServer seems to be operational in that a token can be requested. You can call into an API endpoint and gain access so long as that endpoint had the following attribute:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
```

However, we want the API to be authenticated using both Identity Cookies as well as Bearer tokens, as there is a swagger UI for querying the API when logged in.

Using just the `[Authorize]` attribute will allow it to be accessed via cookies, but not access tokens through Postman (401)

Comment: Which combination of grant types is this, as per http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html - it doesn't sound like you're using the 'forbidden' flow combinations as stipulated at the foot of the page?

Comment: Resource owner password for the app and the website is logged in via standard Identity cookies

Comment: Update your question with the relevant bits of the startup.cs ?

Comment: @spaceBison added some startup config. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is solved but what i personally done to enable API to be authenticated via cookie and bearer token is implement both schemes:

e.g.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddCookie(options => {
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Unauthorized/";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Forbidden/";
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.Audience = "http://localhost:5001/";
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/";
        });
```

In the api controller i use `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthSchemes)]`

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthSchemes)]
public class TodoController: Controller
```

More details on different schemes and usages of them you can have a look here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I achieved a the same thing I believe with: [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer,Identity.Application")]